# How to use temporary object that is passed to super constructor?

Tags: kotlin

```
interface I

open class Base(protected val i: I)

class Impl: I
class Derived(args:Bundle): Base( Impl(args) ) { // here I create an instance of Impl
    private val my: Impl // See my question 
}
```

My `Base` class depends on an interface `I`. But the implementation `Impl` is created in `Derived` class. I want to use `Impl` object in `Derived` class too. I can see the Base implementation and cast `super.i` to `Impl` but I don't want to depends on `Base`'s implementation details. Can I store Impl somewhere to restore in to `Derived.my` member? I have a restriction from the library: a class has to have a constructor with `args:Bundle` argument, no more or less

Comment: what's the reason to not want to depend on `Base`'s implementation details? I feel like this is a non-issue. just write `private val my = i as Impl`

Comment: My question is, is this possible or not under the circumstances?

Comment: this works fine. at least for the example you gave. why not try it out and see for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opposed to simply casting the superclass's property `i as Impl`, you could do this using a secondary constructor and making your primary constructor private:

```
class Derived private constructor(private val my: Impl): Base(my) {

    constructor(args: Bundle): this(Impl(args))

}
```